# Draw Class which extends JLabel

Tags: java, swing, draw, jlabel

I'm trying to draw my "Zone" class which extends JLabel. I don't understand why this is not working, I searched on the website, but I didn't see what is going wrong

Here's my code :

My Board class

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

private List<Zone> zones = new ArrayList<Zone>();

public Board() {
    zones.add(new Zone(1, false, true, dalle1C, null, "/zone1D1C.jpg", 0, 0, this));
    zones.add(new Zone(2, false, false, dalle1C, null, "/zone2D1C.jpg", 150, 0, this));
    zones.add(new Zone(3, false, false, dalle1C, null, "/zone3D1C.jpg", 300, 0, this));
    zones.add(new Zone(4, true, false, dalle1C, null, "/zone4D1C.jpg", 0, 150, this));
    zones.add(new Zone(5, false, false, dalle1C, null, "/zone5D1C.jpg", 300, 150, this));
    zones.add(new Zone(6, true, false, dalle1C, null, "/zone6D1C.jpg", 0, 300, this));
    zones.add(new Zone(7, true, false, dalle1C, null, "/zone7D1C.jpg", 150, 300, this));
    zones.add(new Zone(8, false, false, dalle1C, null, "/zone8D1C.jpg", 300, 300, this));
    zones.get(1).addConnexion(connexion);
    connexion = new PassageGD(zones.get(1), zones.get(2), false, false);
    zones.get(1).addConnexion(connexion);
    connexion = new PassageHB(zones.get(2), zones.get(4), false, false);
    zones.get(4).addConnexion(connexion);
    connexion = new PassageGD(zones.get(3), zones.get(4), false, false);
    zones.get(4).addConnexion(connexion);
    connexion = new PassageHB(zones.get(4), zones.get(7), false, false);
    zones.get(4).addConnexion(connexion);
    connexion = new PassageHB(zones.get(3), zones.get(6), false, false);
    zones.get(6).addConnexion(connexion);
    connexion = new PassageGD(zones.get(5), zones.get(6), false, false);
    zones.get(6).addConnexion(connexion);
    connexion = new PassageHB(zones.get(3), zones.get(5), false, false);
    zones.get(5).addConnexion(connexion);
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    for (Zone zone : zones) {
        this.add(zone);
    }
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}
```

And my Zone class :

```
public class Zone extends JLabel implements ActionListener {
...
...
public Zone(Integer id, boolean piece, boolean egout, Dalle[] dalles, List<Connexion> connexions,    String image_name, Integer x, Integer y, Board board) {
    zone = this;
    addMouseListener(new TAdapter());
    this.board = board;
    if(connexions != null) {
        this.connexions = connexions;
        for(Connexion connexion : connexions) {
            connexion.getOtherZone(this).addConnexion(connexion);
        }
    }
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(image_name));
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x_end = x + image.getWidth(null);
    this.y_end = y + image.getHeight(null);
    this.setBorder(null);
    this.setIcon(ii);
    this.setText(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: BTW - 1) `this.x_end = x + image.getWidth(null);` would better be `this.x_end = x + image.getWidth(this);` 2) `public class Zone extends JLabel implements ActionListener {..` Suggests a button (with icon) to me.

Comment: Thanks I will read what's a MCVE, a button is good but it change the image drawing

Comment: *"a button is good but it change the image drawing"*  Draw the image and set it as the icon for an (undecorated) button and it will look ***exactly*** like a label.

Comment: I have done your method with JButton and his Icon. It's working correctly except for one thing : There is a space between each buttons and the JFrame border. Even if I use the method : `JButton.setBounds(x,y,width,height)` do you have an idea ?

Comment: *"..do you have an idea ?"*  For better help sooner, *post an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).*  But I thought I'd mentioned that in the 1st comment.  O_o

Comment: *"..do you have an idea ?"*  For better help sooner, *post an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).*  But I thought I'd mentioned that in the 1st comment.  O_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't override `paint`, you've broken the paint chain which will affect the ability of the panel to paint it's children. Override `paintComponent` AND call `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting
2. Don't dispose of a `Graphics` context that you didn't create, this could prevent other components from been painted.
3. Don't add components within the `paint` methods, these methods can be called within quick succession and randomly.

Instead, add the components within the constructor

Comment: Thanks it's working fine now, but I got a new problem with a space between each JButton or JLabel (whatever I used)

Comment: JPanel uses FlowLayout by default, you could try using a different layout manager